# How does the "My Tags" customer dashboard feature work?

Tags: customer, tags

My knowledge concerning tags amounts to the fact that tags can be attached
to messages (either within the message or separately at the bottom of the
message) to allow your content to become searchable using those tags
(social media sites as well as ubiquitous for their use, for instance
you can enter `#Magento` on Facebook or `[Magento]` on Stack Overflow in
the search box to display all posts related to such tag).
This is all I know about tags.

Now I would like to know how the Magento "My Tags" feature works (this
feature is visible under "MY ACCOUNT" in the customer dashboard). What
kind of media can be tagged in Magento? Or do I have the wrong idea?
Why would each customer have their own set of tags, rather than the
tags being globally searchable and accessible to all magento customers.
Is it the customer reviews that the customers themselves can tag and
what is the syntax of a tag in Magento?

Thanks for the clarification.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are **two primary types** of "tags" in Magento - **user-submitted** *product tags* and **admin-created** *product tags*. There are **no other tag types** to my knowledge. At the datastore level the tags are related by product ids.

Tags add value to customers looking for similarly tagged items, which become clickable (and, thus, navigable) links on a product page. E.g. tagging a dress as 'summer fashion' would then allow a user to see all other items tagged as summer fashion. This **lends the product page to discovery** in much the way that a category page would do.

Extending upon the functionality or the usefulness of an admin-defined tag, an end-user can submit tags, too. This allows your customers to tag a product (admin-moderated, of course) in much the same way as the Social Media hash-tagging you mentioned in the question.

UGC (User-generated content) is a boon to SEO as it helps your store to be merchandised by the taxonomy of your customers:

[image]

Because vernacular is locale-centric and constantly evolving - tags make an easy way to allow users to refresh content on your product pages.

**Usage**

Tags are moderated. You can accept or reject a tag from the Magento backend:

[image]

When a tag is approved it appears on the product page. There are also frontend views for all tags as well as a sidebar view for popular tags. These features require your theme to have support for them.

Tags don't require any specific formatting. In their most desirable and simple form, they're just plain old keywords. No hashtags required.

**Creative uses**

Some popular uses for tags:

- The obvious SEO benefit
- Creating specific landing pages for PPC campaigns
- In an apparel store, you can associate products by a tag to have on-the-fly pages for shopping a 'look' (e.g. a full outfit) without having to create a full-blown grouped/bundled product. This circumvents the often-misused catalog category for a similar purpose.

[image]

Comment: how can I upvote this twice? This can be the best user manual (even more than that) regarding the magento tags I found so far.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thank you so much for this comprehensive explanation regarding Magento's tag support!